# how to get add a custom-parser in clj-time for AM / PM

Tags: clojure

I am using clj-time for processing dates. I have a date `(def a (date-time 2011 01 01 11 30))`.

I have defined a custom formatter `(def custom-formatter (formatter "hh:mm"))`

Now `(unparse custom-formatter a) => "11:30"`.

However how do I build a formatter which gives me the AM and PM also respectively?

Thanks,
Murtaza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html

To get what you want you need to use something like the following pattern:

```
(formatter "h:mm a")
```